# List GitHub Repo Names

Tags: json, api, github, postman

I am trying to get a list of GitHub Repo names for my organisation.
Using Postman I have used:

```
GET https://api.github.com/orgs/ORGNAME/repos
```

This responds with all of the data for each repo. Is there a way to just return the repo names?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible with the REST API. You need to use their GraphQL API to fetch specific fields.

Answer (score 0):

With the REST Api you will always get the full dataset, but with Graphql you can query your way around to fetch only what you need. here is a sample :

[image]

1. To fetch the data in graphql the method must be POST, put the base url https://api.github.com/graphql
2. in the body of the request select GraphQL. and add the following query in QUERY:

   ```
    query MyQuery {
          nodes(ids: ["#node_id"]) {
        ... on Organization {

      repositories(first: 10) {
        nodes {
          name
        }
      }
    }
   ```

   }
   }

PS: replace node_id with your org node_id

3. in Authorization tab select TYPE Bearer Token and add your Github access token(https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token)

[image]